# php add songID in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, unique

I have a table and I want to add songs into my database. Every song has its own songID , so when I try to add a song it also has to update the songID. at this moment it didn't work.

```
if($action == "add-songs"){

    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);

    if($_GET['action3'] == "2"){        
        mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO songs (id, songName, songID) VALUES (0, '".$_GET['songname']."', '".$_GET['id']."')");                    
        header("Location: /?action=show-songs");
    }   
    $h = "";
    $h.= "";

    $h.= "<form><input type='hidden' name='action' value='add-songs'><input type='hidden' name='action3' value='2'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='id'><table class='table table-striped'>";
    $h.= "  <tr>";
    $h.= "      <td><b>Nummer</b></td>";
    $h.= "      <td><input type='text' name='songname' class='form-control' placeholder='Naam'></td>";
    $h.= "  </tr>";
    $h.= "  <tr>";
    $h.= "      <td colspan='2'><input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='UPDATE'></td>";
    $h.= "  </tr>";
    $h.= "</table></form>";

    echo $htop;
    echo $h;
    echo $hbot;
```

Comment: change this id = 0 to id = ' ' in query

Comment: What `didn't work`?? The SQL, the form submit, the mysql connection. Plz debug your script line by line and find the error first.

Comment: *when I try to add a song it also has to update the songID* , if you're doing  `INSERT` then what does it mean by *it also has to update the songID*? Also, make the *id* column autoincremented, don't insert `0` for all ids, it makes no sense.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions the songID didn't update into my database ... picture : https://gyazo.com/af64241c11dbb8fc2a9dbc071716e376

Comment: OK, but hardly to say something here. Debug your code. Check the SQL berfore you query it....

Comment: Is this your real code? How come *id* column values are `21`, `1`, `2` etc.? You're inserting `0` as *id* value for every row.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I have a auto incremented Id and a songName , but as a artist you can have more songs so you need a songID which Is linked with the album. When I insert a song to my database at the moment it only inserts the name of the song and the id but not the songID

Comment: @RajdeepPaul the first value "21" is the one I inserted as you can see it has no songID.

Comment: Share your database schema as well. Also, see the actual query before inserting, `echo "INSERT INTO songs ....;`

Comment: here is the database , first table "albums" picture : https://gyazo.com/03cc5d8cffd02feda35a074d649da9bc second table "artiest" picture : https://gyazo.com/3a6268e57f71479c7d88d9b85bee4d08 third table is "songs" picture : https://gyazo.com/a741476e4638531e7eefcdfc79c690a9

Comment: @denny what is difference?

Comment: Not sure about the URL but have you tried to `echo` out the queries, like: `echo "INSERT INTO songs (id, ...`? Is it showing the correct query?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul its showing this when I echo the query : picture : https://gyazo.com/42743940d302ac95b9e3f29cbea901f1.  also "test 123" is what I put in the textfield.

Comment: @johnsmith I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** is because of the following `<input>` element,

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='id'>
```

You're using the same **string** value `id` as *id* column value for all of your songs.

Now look at your *songs* table structure, *id* column is of type `INT`, which means you're inserting a string value in the column of type integer. And this is why your business logic is failing.

**The solution** is, don't make the above input element `hidden`. Explicitly put the song id corresponding to the particular song name. So change the above `<input>` element like this:

```
<input type='text' name='id' placeholder='id'>
```

Comment: now it gives me another textfield : picture : https://gyazo.com/42ba6ff3a1f7e0f37087dcb886a6a66a

Comment: @johnsmith Yes, that's the the intended(given) solution. From where else you'll get the song id for a particular song? However, you need to format your table to accommodate those two input fields, right now the design is little bit out of alignment.